# RPI Stops Reading Micro SD Card If I Plugin PI Fans before it and Vice-versa

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

facing issues with the heat sink casing that I bought it got 2 fans.
So, if I connect the fans before the boot RPI doesn't read the micro SD card and no green light. But, if I remove the fans connection from the GPIO then it starts working but, then it will never read the fans and I need to wait for an hour or something to try again.

What could be the solution here?
https://www.amazon.in/Raspberry-Pi-Aluminum-Double-Black/dp/B086VZHCTK/ref=asc_df_B086VZHCTK/?tag=googleshopdes-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=397005670276&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=12530874095350404786&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1007768&hvtargid=pla-936609260103&psc=1&ext_vrnc=hi

Comment: RPI at times be very fussy about power.  Depending on which RPI version it is, a USB connection is not enough to fully power the board.  I found this the hard way.  I had an RPI 2 that came with isn't own power supply.  However, I removed it from its normal environment to debug something and had all kinds of issues getting it to boot.  Eventually, I saw the little lightning bolt in the corner of the screen as it was booting.  I fetch the power supply and used that to power the RPI and suddenly everything was working.

Comment: I assume you are using a Pi4, what power supply are you using?